# Datastax Cassandra C/C++ driver cass_cluster_set_blacklist_filtering functionality

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Datastax C/C++ driver has a blacklist filtering functionality as part of its load balancing controls.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/2.5/topics/configuration/

Correct me If I missing something but my understanding is that a CQL client can't connect to blacklisted hosts.

I'm using C/C++ driver v2.5 and the below codeblock and trying to connect to a multinode cluster:

```
CassCluster* cluster = cass_cluster_new();
CassSession* session = cass_session_new();
const char* hosts    = "192.168.57.101";
cass_cluster_set_contact_points(cluster, hosts);
cass_cluster_set_blacklist_filtering(cluster, hosts);
CassFuture* connect_future = cass_session_connect(session, cluster);
```

In this codeblock the host to which the CQL client is trying to connect is set as blacklisted. However, CQL client seems to connect to this host and executes any queries. Is there something wrong with the above codeblock? If not so, is this the expected behavior? Does it behaves differently because it is a multinode cluster and establish connection to the other peers?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are supplying only one contact point, that IP address is being used to establish the control connection into the cluster. Once that control connection is established and the peers table is read to determine other nodes available in the cluster, connections are made to those other nodes. At this point all queries will be routed to those other nodes and not your initial/blacklisted contact point; however the connection to the initial contact point will remain as it is the control connection into the cluster.

To get a better look at what is going on inside the driver you can enable logging in the driver. Here is an example to enable logging via the console:

```
void on_log(const CassLogMessage* message, void* data) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%u.%03u [%s] (%s:%d:%s): %s\n",
  (unsigned int) (message->time_ms / 1000),
  (unsigned int) (message->time_ms % 1000),
  cass_log_level_string(message->severity),
  message->file, message->line, message->function,
  message->message);
}

/* Log configuration *MUST* be done before any other driver call */
cass_log_set_level(CASS_LOG_TRACE);
cass_log_set_callback(on_log, NULL);
```

In order to reduce the extra connection on a node that will be blacklisted you can supply a different contact point into the cluster that is not the same as the node (or nodes) that will be blacklisted.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Blacklist policy is supported by C/C++ driver. There is also the whitelist policy which is supported by C/C++ driver and other languages drivers. With whitelist policy of C/C++ driver the client connects to a node even if it's not included in whitelist but stores any data in the whitelist hosts (works the same way as blacklist). With whitelist policy of Python driver the client doesn't connect to nodes not included in whitelist. So, I assume that datastax drivers of different languages might have different implementations of the whitelist policy.

Comment: @MariosBraho You are correct, the python driver respects the whitelist hosts and does not establish a connection to the host. I have created a ticket on the DataStax C/C++ Jira board if you wish to track it ; https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CPP-447.